# Posting image content to FaceBook from behind firewall using Perl FaceBook::Graph

Tags: perl, facebook-graph-api, perl-module

This question is somewhat specific to Perl FaceBook::Graph API and may not relate to Facebook Graph in general. What I'm attempting to do is to try to post a photo using Perl and the FaceBook::Graph module. The module documentation ([http://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::Graph](http://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook%3a%3aGraph)) indicates that I need the "publish_stream" privilege post publish a photo, but this generates a "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." error whereas a regular message post works without error. In checking my token with the Access Token Debugger I get the following information:

```
App ID: [removed]: [removed]
Metadata: []
User ID: [removed] : [removed]
Issued: Unknown
Expires: 1372705200 (in about an hour)
Valid: True
Origin: Web
Scopes: create_note photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream share_item status_update user_photos video_upload
```

Unfortunately, the CPAN documentation for the "Facebook::Graph::Publish::Photo" module is a bit lacking and I can't locate a complete Perl example for posting a photo that doesn't reference the same code. More complete example code by me below:

```
#note: this is not the complete code I'm using, quite a few non-FB related lines left out for simplicity

#create the 
my $FBHandle=Facebook::Graph->new(
    app_id => $TargetFBAppID, #passed in as an arg
    secret => $TargetFBAppSecret, #passed in as an arg
    postback => $TargetFBAppPostBack #passed in as an arg
);

#make sure this is valid when passing it in
my $AccessTokenResult=$FBHandle->access_token($FBAccessToken); #passed in as an arg, generated by FB's Access Token Debugger

if(!$AccessTokenResult) {
    $FaultString="No FB access token returned";
} else {
    #do the image post
    my $PostHash=$FBHandle->add_photo()
        ->set_source($TempFileResultHash->{"fullpath"}) #works out to "C:/Tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/webapps/service_api/temp/FacebookBroadcast-F38365F5-6D00-1014-9DBD-87D476B3CC17"
        ->set_message($OptionsHash->{"message"}||"") #passed in from args
    ;

    #add_post works, but not add_photo
    #my $PostHash=$FBHandle->add_post()
    #   ->set_message($OptionsHash->{"message"}||"") #passed in from args
    #;

    #send it
    my $PostResultHash=$PostHash->publish(); #need "publish_stream" priv for this to work

    die Data::Dumper::Dumper($PostResultHash); #dump the result
} #end if
```

Anyone have an idea where I might be going wrong?

Further edit: The FaceBook::Graph add_note() and add_link() methods also work without issue, provided the correct privs are added to the access token, but add_photo() still throws an error.

Comment: I resolved the issue. The problem was a bug in the Facebook::Graph::Request module.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the Facebook::Graph::Response code (version 1.0500) where the $params argument is not passing all of the required elements into the sub, resulting in a "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." error (because the token was never sent by the sub). Because add_photo is the only is function to make use of the post sub all other functions (add_link, add_note, add_post, etc.) will work correctly.

To resolve the issue, edit the Facebook::Graph::Request module and locate the post sub around line 24 and change the two references (in this sub only) from "$params" to "@params".

From this ...

```
sub post {
    my ($self, $uri, $params) = @_;
    my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
    $self->ua->post_async($uri, $params)->cb(sub {
        $cv->send(Facebook::Graph::Response->new(response => shift->recv));
    });
    return $cv;
}
```

To this...

```
sub post {
    my ($self, $uri, @params) = @_;
    my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
    $self->ua->post_async($uri, @params)->cb(sub {
        $cv->send(Facebook::Graph::Response->new(response => shift->recv));
    });
    return $cv;
}
```

After making these changes you code should now work as expected assuming your access token is valid and similar calls to functions such as add_post already work.

Further edit: This issue appears to be corrected in the CPAN and ActiveState versions of the code (v1.0600). Check is this fix is applicable before making the code edits mentioned above.